# Problem getting semi transparency to work in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, image, 2d

I've made some images in Krita (drawing software) with both full and semi transparency involved. I can get the full transparency to work after importing the image to Blender, but not the semitransparency.

[image]

Here is the image above. The light green border around the edge is what I want to be semi transparent, but it isn't showing up correctly in Blender.

[image]

Here is the image in Blenders editor above. Here the light green border barely shows at all. Last but not least:

[image]

Above is the image after rendering. The light green border shows up, but isn't transparent at all.
I have used the original image in other programs and I know that the semitransparency works, but I have no idea how to do it in Blender and all search results I find just tell me how to do full transparency, which I already know. Can anyone help me out?

**Here is a link to my blend file** https://ufile.io/qubd3gla
And the first image I posted (above) is the actual picture used as the image texture.

Comment: Could you please share your file? (only the object with the image, don't forget to pack the image)

Comment: That the light green border is barely showing in the editor has most likely the following reason: in the _Material Properties_ under _Viewport Display_ the _Blend Mode_ is set to _Alpha Clip_. This means, it either displays fully opaque or fully transparent, nothing inbetween. The _Clip Threshold_ value determines the transition. Let's say your green border has an alpha value of 0.5 and the threshold is set to 0.6, then it will be transparent. If the threshold is 0.4, it will be opaque.

Comment: For the rendered image: hard to tell how transparent the green border is - since it is not fully transparent, it will be affected by lighting. The environment seems quite bright and a light color (even on a semi-transparent material) will reflect much light. Another thing is the uniform background does not provide any features that could be visible through a semi-transparent surface. Without knowing your exact material setup, the alpha channel of the image and the environment settings it is hard to tell what is the problem there - so I agree with @moonboots asking for the file.

Answer (score 0):

For the disappearing border in the *Material Preview* it is exactly like I said in the comments: in the *Material Properties* under *Viewport Display*, the *Blend Mode* is set to *Alpha Clip*, the *Clip Threshold* is set to 0.5, which means everything below this value is fully transparent, everything above is fully opaque. The alpha of the light green border has a brightness value of 0.238, so it is below the threshold and therefore fully transparent in *Material Preview*.

The reason it does not look transparent in *Rendered View* is also the one I gave in the comments. The light green border is a very bright color and can reflect very much light, even when it is semi-transparent - and you have a bright light shining on it. To this adds the fact that it is a green border over a green background which makes the transparency even harder to see.

In order to show you that there really is transparency even though you don't see it, I reduced the bright area light a lot and also made the background color red and even applied red emission to it. Now you get an idea that there is transparency:

[image: semi-transparency]

Because if I disable the *Alpha* channel, the result looks like this: the dark green is the same since it has been opaque before, but the light green border looks a lot different:

[image: alpha disabled]

If you want the border to be more transparent, you can for example plug a *Color Ramp* between the *Alpha* output of the image and the *Alpha* input of the *Principled BSDF* and move the black slider until it is transparent enough. Or maybe use a *Map Range* node to adjust the values. In the following image I'm still using the red background to make it more visible, but you should maybe adjust it on the actual background to find a suitable value:

[image: decreased alpha]